# Pyorient batch parsing issue

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

I am currently trying to fill an orientdb graph database using pyorient. In general, everything works well. However, I have stumbled across a parsing issue with one of my commands. In Python if I run the following code:

```
>>> ab = 'UPDATE Patent SET  primary_id = 676, original_abstract = set(original_abstract, "<p num=\\"0000\\">The present invention relates to compounds of the general formula (I) wherein\\n\\nR<sup>1</sup> is the group (A) or (B) or (C) or (D); R<sup>2</sup> is a non aromatic\\n\\nheterocycle, or is OR\' or N(R\\")<sub>2</sub>; R\' is lower alkyl,\\n\\nlower alkyl substituted by halogen or -(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>n</sub>-cycloalkyl;\\n\\nR\\" is lower alkyl; R<sup>3</sup> is NO<sub>2</sub>, CN or SO<sub>2</sub>R\';\\n\\nR<sup>4 </sup>is hydrogen, hydroxy, halogen, NO<sub>2</sub>, lower alkyl, lower\\n\\nalkyl, substituted by halogen, lower alkoxy, SO<sub>2</sub>R\' or C(O)OR\\";\\n\\nR<sup>5</sup>/R<sup>6</sup>/R<sup>7</sup> are hydrogen, halogen, lower alkyl\\n\\nor lower alkyl, substituted by halogen; X<sup>1</sup>/X<sup>1\\u00bf</sup>\\n\\nare CH or N, with the proviso that X<sup>1</sup>/X<sup>1\\u00bf</sup> are not simultaneously\\n\\nCH; X<sup>2</sup> is O, S, NH or N(lower alkyl); n is 0, l or 2; and to pharmaceutically\\n\\nactive acid addition salts and to their use in the treatment of neurological and\\n\\nneuropsychiatric disorders.</p>")  UPSERT WHERE primary_id = 676'
>>> client.batch(ab)
```

I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/orient.py", line 402, in batch
.prepare(( QUERY_SCRIPT, ) + args).send().fetch_response()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/commands.py", line 145, in fetch_response
    super( CommandMessage, self ).fetch_response()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 256, in fetch_response
self._decode_all()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 240, in _decode_all


 self._decode_header()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 192, in _decode_header
    [ exception_message.decode( 'utf8' ) ]
pyorient.exceptions.PyOrientCommandException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.TokenMgrError - Lexical error at line 1, column 311.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "\"<p num=\\\"0000\\\">The present invention relates to compounds of the general formula (I) wherein\\n\\nR<sup>1</sup> is the group (A) or (B) or (C) or (D); R<sup>2</sup> is a non aromatic\\n\\nheterocycle, or is OR\' or N(R\\\")<sub>2</sub>"
```

If I run this using command I also get errors:

```
>>> client.command(ab)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/orient.py", line 398, in command
    .prepare(( QUERY_CMD, ) + args).send().fetch_response()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/commands.py", line 145, in fetch_response
    super( CommandMessage, self ).fetch_response()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 256, in fetch_response
    self._decode_all()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 240, in _decode_all
    self._decode_header()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 192, in _decode_header
    [ exception_message.decode( 'utf8' ) ]
pyorient.exceptions.PyOrientCommandException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingExceptioncom.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException - Error on parsing command at position #0: Error on reading parameters in: set(original_abstract, "<p num="0000">The present invention relates to compounds of the general formula (I) wherein

R<sup>1</sup> is the group (A) or (B) or (C) or (D); R<sup>2</sup> is a non aromatic

heterocycle, or is OR' or N(R")<sub>2</sub>; R' is lower alkyl,

lower alkyl substituted by halogen or -(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>n</sub>-cycloalkyl;

R" is lower alkyl; R<sup>3</sup> is NO<sub>2</sub>, CN or SO<sub>2</sub>R';

R<sup>4 </sup>is hydrogen, hydroxy, halogen, NO<sub>2</sub>, lower alkyl, lower

alkyl, substituted by halogen, lower alkoxy, SO<sub>2</sub>R' or C(O)OR";

R<sup>5</sup>/R<sup>6</sup>/R<sup>7</sup> are hydrogen, halogen, lower alkyl

or lower alkyl, substituted by halogen; X<sup>1</sup>/X<sup>1¿</sup>

are CH or N, with the proviso that X<sup>1</sup>/X<sup>1¿</sup> are not simultaneously

CH; X<sup>2</sup> is O, S, NH or N(lower alkyl); n is 0, l or 2; and to pharmaceutically

active acid addition salts and to their use in the treatment of neurological and

neuropsychiatric disordersFound invalid ) character at position 229 of text original_abstract, "<p num="0000">The present invention relates to compounds of the general formula (I) wherein

R<sup>1</sup> is the group (A) or (B) or (C) or (D); R<sup>2</sup> is a non aromatic

heterocycle, or is OR' or N(R")<sub>2</sub>. Ensure it is opened and closed correctly.
```

I have found however that if I do not add the information under original_abstract as a set, it works when using command:

```
>>> aba = 'UPDATE Patent SET  primary_id = 676, original_abstract = "<p num=\\"0000\\">The present invention relates to compounds of the general formula (I) wherein\\n\\nR<sup>1</sup> is the group (A) or (B) or (C) or (D); R<sup>2</sup> is a non aromatic\\n\\nheterocycle, or is OR\' or N(R\\")<sub>2</sub>; R\' is lower alkyl,\\n\\nlower alkyl substituted by halogen or -(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>n</sub>-cycloalkyl;\\n\\nR\\" is lower alkyl; R<sup>3</sup> is NO<sub>2</sub>, CN or SO<sub>2</sub>R\';\\n\\nR<sup>4 </sup>is hydrogen, hydroxy, halogen, NO<sub>2</sub>, lower alkyl, lower\\n\\nalkyl, substituted by halogen, lower alkoxy, SO<sub>2</sub>R\' or C(O)OR\\";\\n\\nR<sup>5</sup>/R<sup>6</sup>/R<sup>7</sup> are hydrogen, halogen, lower alkyl\\n\\nor lower alkyl, substituted by halogen; X<sup>1</sup>/X<sup>1\\u00bf</sup>\\n\\nare CH or N, with the proviso that X<sup>1</sup>/X<sup>1\\u00bf</sup> are not simultaneously\\n\\nCH; X<sup>2</sup> is O, S, NH or N(lower alkyl); n is 0, l or 2; and to pharmaceutically\\n\\nactive acid addition salts and to their use in the treatment of neurological and\\n\\nneuropsychiatric disorders.</p>"  UPSERT WHERE primary_id = 676'
>>> client.command(aba)
['1']
```

However client.batch still cannot handle this correctly:

```
>>> client.batch(aba)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/orient.py", line 402, in batch
    .prepare(( QUERY_SCRIPT, ) + args).send().fetch_response()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/commands.py", line 145, in fetch_response
    super( CommandMessage, self ).fetch_response()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 256, in fetch_response
    self._decode_all()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 240, in _decode_all
    self._decode_header()
  File "/Users/shaungupta/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 192, in _decode_header
    [ exception_message.decode( 'utf8' ) ]
pyorient.exceptions.PyOrientCommandException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException - Found invalid ) character at position 274 of text UPDATE Patent SET  primary_id = 676, original_abstract = "<p num=\"0000\">The present invention relates to compounds of the general formula (I) wherein\n\nR<sup>1</sup> is the group (A) or (B) or (C) or (D); R<sup>2</sup> is a non aromatic\n\nheterocycle, or is OR' or N(R\")<sub>2</sub>; R' is lower alkyl,\n\nlower alkyl substituted by halogen or -(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>n</sub>-cycloalkyl;\n\nR\" is lower alkyl; R<sup>3</sup> is NO<sub>2</sub>, CN or SO<sub>2</sub>R';\n\nR<sup>4 </sup>is hydrogen, hydroxy, halogen, NO<sub>2</sub>, lower alkyl, lower\n\nalkyl, substituted by halogen, lower alkoxy, SO<sub>2</sub>R' or C(O)OR\";\n\nR<sup>5</sup>/R<sup>6</sup>/R<sup>7</sup> are hydrogen, halogen, lower alkyl\n\nor lower alkyl, substituted by halogen; X<sup>1</sup>/X<sup>1\u00bf</sup>\n\nare CH or N, with the proviso that X<sup>1</sup>/X<sup>1\u00bf</sup> are not simultaneously\n\nCH; X<sup>2</sup> is O, S, NH or N(lower alkyl); n is 0, l or 2; and to pharmaceutically\n\nactive acid addition salts and to their use in the treatment of neurological and\n\nneuropsychiatric disorders.</p>"  UPSERT WHERE primary_id = 676. Ensure it is opened and closed correctly.
```

Running string ab directly in the orientdb console also gives the same errors, however running string aba in the orientdb console works fine, so I cannot understand why aba does not work with the pyorient batch command (I also have managed to run aba in the orientdb console as part of a begin/commit transaction with success).

Does anybody understand why this command works via client.command and not client.batch? I need to have this command running as part of a batch of commands, so need to find a fix..... Ideally, I would like to have the command in string ab where I am adding original abstract as a set to work, as I need to keep track of any new information for matching nodes.

From what I can see this is a parsing limitation of the command executor, but please do tell me if I am doing something wrong here...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The first error shows you have End of File (EOF) character in your command which might not be visible, It is common if it is copied from somewhere else.